# Missing Entries When Exporting a Python Dictionary to Another Notebook

Tags: python, dictionary, import, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with my python code that creates a dictionary. The dictionary is created correctly, but when I export it to another notebook and print it there, some entries are missing.

Here is the code I use to create the dictionary:

```
def extract_top_projects(tmp_orders_dict, branch_name):
    # Filter projects by branch
    project_values = [(k, v) for k, v in tmp_orders_dict['Erw. AE gewichtet'].items() if k[0] == branch_name]
    sorted_projects = sorted(project_values, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
    
    branch_dict = {}
    branch_name_formatted = branch_names[branch_name]

    for i in range(len(sorted_projects)):
        project_name_var = f"branch_{branch_name_formatted}_project_{i+1}_name"
        project_value_var = f"branch_{branch_name_formatted}_project_{i+1}_value"
        project_name = tmp_orders_dict['Auftrag oder Projekt Bez.'][sorted_projects[i][0]]
        project_value = round(sorted_projects[i][1] / 1000000,3)  # convert values to millions
        
        branch_dict[project_name_var] = project_name
        branch_dict[project_value_var] = project_value
    
    return branch_dict

# Branch names mapping
branch_names = {"Central": "ce", "East": "ea", "West": "we"}

# Create the dict
tmp_orders_qtg = {}
for branch_name in branch_names.keys():
    tmp_orders_qtg.update(extract_top_projects(tmpqtg23, branch_name))
```

I suspect that the problem occurs when exporting and importing the dictionary, but I'm not sure exactly where the problem is. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem could be and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

I have created a dictionary `tmp_orders_qtg` using my Python function `extract_top_projects`. This function extracts the top projects for each branch ("Central", "East", and "West") from a larger dictionary `tmpqtg23` and returns a new dictionary for each branch. I then updated the `tmp_orders_qtg` dictionary with these branch-specific dictionaries.

What I Expected To Happen:

I expected `tmp_orders_qtg` to contain all the entries from each of the branch-specific dictionaries, correctly preserving the project names and their corresponding values.

What Actually Happened:

While `tmp_orders_qtg` seems to be correctly populated within the current notebook, when I export this dictionary to another notebook and print it, some entries are missing. It seems that not all data from the `extract_top_projects` function is being preserved in the `tmp_orders_qtg` dictionary upon export, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you talk a little more about what "export it to another notebook" is doing and/or explain how you are doing that?